# Flutter plugins not working (No implementation found for method X on channel flutter.plugins.io/Y)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am getting this error with almost every plugin I install (Facebook login, Google sign in and Image picker so far).
My flutter project is built using Kotlin and Swift support as well as AndroidX.

I have already tried to clean Flutter build cache using `flutter clean`, and algo uninstalling the app from the emulator.

This is my `pubspec.yaml`

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  material_design_icons_flutter: 3.2.3895
  image_picker: ^0.6.1+8
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+1
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.6
  flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.1 
  flutter_bloc: ^0.20.1
  equatable: ^0.2.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  module:
    androidX: true
  assets:
    - lib/assets/
```

I am having this issue on Android for now, I am not developing iOS app at the moment.

Every issue on Flutter's Github end up saying "just type flutter clean and you are good to go" but this is not solving anything.

Comment: Do you use the Flutter's native host, or do you embed the Flutter page into another host?

Comment: I don't even know what are you referring to, so I guess I am using the default config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `flutter pub get`.

Then find the class `io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant` in **ANDROID project**.

Make sure the facebook plugin load there:

```java
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
      return;
    }
    FacebookLoginPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.roughike.facebooklogin.facebooklogin.FacebookLoginPlugin"));

    // load other plugin code...

  }
```

Comment: Found the mentioned class, the line where Facebook plugin registers is not there, nor there is any other plugin registration. Do you know why and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you run `flutter pub get` in you project directory? Can you show me that output message? @sbd2

Comment: I did and the output was `exit code 0`. By the way I managed to solve this by just opening the `MainActivity.kt` file and manually adding the plugin registrations. After that (and rebuilding), the non-working plugins started to work perfecty. I would love to know why this is not happening automatically (if you know please share that information). I will accept this answer as correct because it put me on the right track to get the problem solved.

Comment: Example of `MainActivity.kt` with added registration: 
`class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
    FacebookLoginPlugin.registerWith(this.registrarFor("com.roughike.facebooklogin.facebooklogin.FacebookLoginPlugin"))
    ImagePickerPlugin.registerWith(this.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin"))
  }
}`

Comment: Congratulations! It's seem that flutter build tool can't modify file `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.kt`. I guest that 
 your file `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.kt` was read-only. Make sure that file is not read-only, then run `flutter pub get` again. @sbd2

Comment: Nope, I have verified that both `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java` and `MainActivity.kt` are not read-only (and even granted modify permissions for my user, just in case). So I don't have a clue why this happens.

Comment: I think you lost file: [setting.gradle](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/hello_world/android/settings.gradle). This gradle file is used to generate `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java`

Comment: I do have it, this is its content `include ':app'

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you setup the Facebook login plugin as per the instructions i.e the androidmanifest.xml, in the Facebook developer account, the build.gradle and in the firebase console for your plugin. The same for Google Sign in. 
If that is in order, I suggest you comment out the plugins and build to see when the error comes up.

Comment: For Facebook Login I have done the complete setup (got it working on another app, I don't know why it is not working here). For the case of ImagePicker, documentation says it should work out of the box (which is not exactly true since I had to add the storage permission) but it is not working either.